# How do I answer my Own Question?

Tags: discussion, support, editing

Tonight I successfully resolved [my own question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126297/new-problems-installing-ati-catalyst-driver-in-12-04-lts) after getting into some difficulties.  The resolution in the end was simple and came straight from the [Ubuntu Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI).

The reason why I am asking "How do I answer my own question" is because there is a trail which may cause confusion (historically) if members click on associated links etc.  Let me explain:

[I asked this question a while ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-in-12-04-lts).  It was closed and I was told it was a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-in-12-04-lts).  I took this at face value and followed these instructions that got me into difficulties today, (hence my new question)

While you guys have the decision, I think it would be appropriate (cleaner) to reopen my original question and put the answer there and reference this with a Problem solved 
link back to the original on my new question.  Maybe you have other rules of how to tidy things up.  My intent is good as I dont want future members to run into the same difficulties as I did.  let me know what approach I should take and I will follow up

By the way, I forgot to mention, the final resolution was completely different from the instruction I was following

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here - do you want to have that question reopened, and then you want to answer it, right?

Comment: Yes that right (only because thats the right place for the answer) From my perspective. You might not agree.  I think it would be helpful to others to have the answer there

Comment: Well done on the followthrough, upvotes all around from me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your original question is reopened.

As for if you can, go right ahead - [this stackexchange blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) states:

> To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.**