# Is it considered proper conduct creating a question just for the purpose of providing an answer that I consider very useful?

Tags: discussion, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ought one to answer one's own question?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/111/ought-one-to-answer-ones-own-question)

Asking certain questions, I found answers to other questions that I have not yet posted and that I consider very important. Now, I know the answer to the later  questions, but I would like to share these answers with others.

A specification of this question would be: Is it considered proper conduct answering my own questions?

Comment: Yes. In fact, by design, when you ask a question there's a checkbox option for answering it straight off.

Comment: So, what I can do by design I also may do by rule of conduct. But I do not think this question is a duplicate. As one respondent said to the former question you mentioned: "If you knew the answer all along, you probably shouldn't have asked the question." But I specifically am referring to a situation when I want to create the question exactly for that reason.

Comment: @cipricus "If you knew the answer all along, you probably shouldn't have asked the question" this means, AFAIK, You should not create too localized question, which may be only applicable to a very few cases

Comment: I found here (http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3005/47206) an answer that goes in the same direction. So, it is 'yes'. Please put comments as answers so I would not answer it myself ... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! If you think the question will be useful to others, do it!

Comment: too late for that. but the answer is visible